# Camera SurfaceView flicker in view pager while scrolling

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, fragmentstatepageradapter

In my App I am using ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter to display 4 different layout.
Layout 1 , 3 , 4 consists of ListView and 2nd layout contains SurfaceView Camera. Now when I am scrolling horizontally camera at the both edges get flicker.

I search on google, and find different solutions. like 
1) giving minus margin with android:layout_gravity = "center".
2) viewPager.requestTransparentRegion(viewPager);

Here in first case, it works good at first time but when comming back from resume it cuts from right showing black rectangle.

also I have also tried with different parent layout but the same scenario
happened and also tried to give margin programmatically, but could not find any solution.

Here is my Camera xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="-100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my fragment adapter.

```
public class DashboardAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

 public DashboardAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(new InboxFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new CameraFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new ContactFragment());
    fragmentList.add(new AddFriendsFragmnet());
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return InboxFragment.newInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return CameraFragment.newInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return ContactFragment.newInstance(position);
        case 3:
            return AddFriendsFragmnet.newInstance(position);
        default:
            return CameraFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container,   position);
    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
}
```

}

Any help would be too much thankful.

Comment: Hi, Finally after a so much stuff , I have solved this issue by replacing SurfaceView by TextureView. Below link helps me in "TextureView" with camera.   [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textureview.htm).  If any body wnats than I can share the peace of actual code I have used in my project.

Comment: If you've found a solution, don't wait for someone to come ask you, just post it as answer and accept/mark it as answer. It's okay if you come up with a solution yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced SurfaceView with TextureView to open a camera.

[Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_textureview.htm)

Here is a link for an example of TextureView Camera. It's working now.

Thanks